# My VSTS pull request shows diffs between two branches when none exist

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to understand what's happening here because this is tripping me up.

Let's say I have two long lived branches.  `() - Master` and `[] - Develop`.  The current state of my repo looks like this:

`()  <-- Master
   \
    \
     []--[]--[] <--Develop`

I introduce a `{} - hotfix` branch off master with changes that need to go into both Master and Develop.

`()--{} <-- Hotfix (needs to go into both Master & Develop)
   \
    \
     []--[]--[] <--Develop`

I merge hotfix into both Master and Develop via separate Pull Requests.

```
   _ _ _ _ _
  /         \
 ()----{}---() <-- Master /w hotfix changes
   \    \_ _ _ _ _
    \             \
     []--[]--[]----[] <--Develop /w hotfix changes
```

At this point I notice two things in VSTS' pull request diffing UI:

- If I create *yet another* pull request for hotfix into Master or Develop (recall that both long-lived branches already contain the hotfix changes from a prior PR), the web-based diffing UI still shows a diff between hotfix and Master or Develop.
- If I create a pull request for develop into master, it shows a diff of the changes contained in hotfix (but those changes are already in both Master and Develop).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point is **how VSTS complete a PR for a fast-forward merge**.

Assume there are two branches (`branch1` and `branch2`) with below commit history:

```
…---A   branch1
     \
      B  branch2
```

If you merge `branch2` into `branch1` by default manner (fast-forward), such as by executing `git merge branch2` command directly, `branch1` and `branch2` will point to the same commit  `B` as below:

```
…---A---B   branch1, branch2
```

But for VSTS, it complete a PR with no-fast-forward, as the command **`git merge --no-ff`**. So even it’s a fast-forward merge, there will create a merge commit.

So if you create a PR to merge `branch2` into `branch1` (or use the command `git merge branch2 --no-ff`), the commit history will be:

```
…---A---C   branch1
     \ /
      B   branch2
```

While if you create a PR to merge back `branch1` into `branch2` in VSTS (actually it's unnecessary), it  allow you to create the PR since the commit `C` from `branch1` is not on `branch2`.

Now go back to your situation, the commit history original as below:

```
  H1  hotfix
 /
M1    master
 \
  D1---D2---D3  develop
```

When you first create the two pull requests to merge `hotfix` into `master` and `hotfix` into `develop` separately, after completing the two pull request, the commit history looks like:

```
M1-------M2    master
 \      /
  \---H1----------   hotfix
   \              \
    D1---D2---D3---D4  develop
```

So if you create another PR to merge `master`/`develop` branch into `hotfix`, VSTS will allow you to create the PR since  `master`/`develop` branch and `hotfix` branch are point to different commits. But it’s actually unnecessary to merge the changes back.

And it you create a PR to merge `develop` branch into `master` branch, it not only shows the diff for commit `D1`, `D2` and `D3`, but also show the diff commits `M2` and `D4` (even though they contains same changes from `hotfix` branch) since they are different commits.

**BTW:**

- Based on your workflow, `master` is the main branch, and all the works are developed on `develop` branch. When it’s ready, merge `develop` branch into `master` branch.
- For bug fixing, it does need to branch off `hotfix` branch from `master` branch. But when fix the bug on `hotfix` branch, you’d better **merge `hotfix` into `develop` branch, and then merge `develop` branch into `master` branch**. This can make the history more clearly.